# get some list element index based on another list elements

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have two list :

```
a=['book','car','car','have']
b=['car','have']
```

I want this output:

```
a_basedon_b_indexes=[1,2,3]# 'car' and 'have' indexes in list a
```

i want a one line expression for this output.(i know how to do it with for loop).is this possible in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to iterate over `a` along with the indices in a list comprehension,

```
>>> b = set(b)
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x in b]
[1, 2, 3]
```

I've used a `set` for efficiency (membership tests are constant time operations).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerate` in a list comprehension for this

```
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(a) if j in b]
[1, 2, 3]
```

If `b` is large, I'd recommend using a `set` as the `in` operation will be faster

```
>>> b = {'car', 'have'}
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(a) if j in b]
[1, 2, 3]
```